# JAXB как игнорировать поля суперкласса?

Tags: java, soap, serialize, jaxb

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Есть сторонняя библиотека (по понятным причинам не модифицируемая), я наследую свой класс от одного из её абстрактных классов.
Дальше я этот класс сериализую JAXB и отдаю по SOAP (подключаю только энтерпрайз, отдельно библиотеки не тяну, всё из пакета javax).

Проблема: JAXB хватает поля абстрактного (супер) класса, что нежелательно (они даже в xsd не описаны, и следовательно без неймспейса отдаются).

Вопрос: как игнорировать все поля всех суперклассов, либо как игнорировать все поля, не отмеченные `@XmlElement`?

Я пробовал следующее:

1. `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` на текущий класс (который, собственно, и уходит на сериализацию)
2. Пробовал сделать промежуточный класс, и `@XmlTransient` на него
3. Пробовал перезаписывать геттеры полей, которые мне мешают, и `@XmlTransient` на них

Ни чего из этого не помогает, такое ощущение, что JAXB просто забил на аннотации...

Вот что получаю:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<S:Body>
    <ns3:GetBonusStatusRequest xmlns:ns3="http://some.soap.wsdl.ru/path/to/them/SelfCarePortal">
        <execDelay>0</execDelay>
        <name>com.xxx.protocol.sip.impl.GetBonusStatusSipRequest</name>
        <poolId>sip</poolId>
        <ns3:svcNum>xxxxxx</ns3:svcNum>
        <ns3:SAN>xxxxxxx</ns3:SAN>
    </ns3:GetBonusStatusRequest>
</S:Body>
```

Соответственно, поля execDelay, name, poolId мне не нужны, они не описаны протоколом.
Jackson, к примеру, умеет в `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"poolId", "frontendId", "name", "execDate", "execDelay", "cancelled"})` а вот JAXB что-то подкачал...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Необходимо отметить родительский класс @XmlTransient
2. В EclipseLink JAXB есть решение данной проблем(http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/EclipseLink-OXM.XML)
   пример работы с аннотация

> ```
> <java-types>
>
>     <java-type name="java.util.logging.LogRecord" xml-transient="true"/>
>
> </java-types>
> ```